# ASP.NET Core: dependency injection — analogue of autofac modules

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm configuring DI container to be able to resolve several services inside my app.
If I would have used autofac, I would use modules from there to logically bundle registrations.
**Does ASP.NET core framework has analogues for modules? How can I achieve that if I want?**

[Official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) on DI says:
[image]
**Does that mean that I shouldn't be looking for module system anymore?**
And if I have like 20-50 services, it's best to create an extension for each separate one?

Comment: I think it's saying create extension methods for groups of related services, like `AddMvc()` adds a group of MVC-related services... I mean, it says, "...to encapsulate groups of service registrations."

Comment: @HereticMonkey, thanks for the info. Probably I misunderstood meaning of that sentence. Guess you are correct and I should hide related services under one extension. Could you please put that as an answer?

Comment: No, `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` is intentionally simplistic. However, if you want to use Autofac, there's nothing stopping you. https://docs.autofac.org/en/v4.0.0/integration/aspnetcore.html

Comment: @ChrisPratt, thanks for the info, it's useful. I don't think that mixing two DI frameworks in one application is a good idea, especially adding autofac just for the sake of modules, so I wanted to migrate everything on core framework's abilities.

Comment: It's not technically using two DI frameworks. `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` acts as a facade with a default and simplistic provider. When you plugin something like Autofac, it takes over as the provider, and all you're using is the facade layer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is nothing comparable to autofac's modules registration in the core DI implementations.
You would have to implement it on your own, which should not become a really big deal.